# android - Mail app not support in nexus 7

Tags: android, email

I want to send some message to particular email ID. I set the to address and trying to send messages. it's working fine in Gmail App. but it's not working properly in the Mail App especially in Nexus 7(HTC one V also) what the reason behind?

**Source Code**

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");   
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:naresh.repalle@shoregrp.com"));
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Price Check Guru Feedback");        
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

***Updated Code***

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            emailIntent.setType("text/html");

```
        //set the To address and Subject
        try
        {
            String strSubject = URLEncoder.encode("Price Check Guru Feedback","UTF-8");         
            //testing
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:naresh.repalle@shoregrp.com"+ "?subject=" + strSubject));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Comment: Not working properly? Can you show us the error you're getting.

Comment: Not working properly means i am not receiving any message using Mail app but using Gmail app it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite all the rumours which people spread on forums (and also here), **not all Android e-mail apps support a mixture of `SENDTO`/`mailto:` and `EXTRA`s**. Period. You've chosen an approach which is not supported by all apps (including K-9), that's all.

What *seems* to work is including the subject and body in the URL with `?subject=` and `&body=`, using `Uri.encode()`. *However*, please be aware that the standard Android e-mail client V3.0 *erases all `+` signs form such a message*, probably due to wrong decoding.

*Update:* Okay so that's not your problem; lucky you. Of course, you can force the system to provide the chooser; have you not googled your problem? Although, if it does not fire, it means that the user chose Google mail over the proprietary e-mail program before.

Comment: Then what should i do that supports all the Apps?

Comment: it's working fine in nexus 7 but in HTC one v is not working(i am unable to receive messages using mail app). i update the code plz check it once

Comment: @naresh Do yourself a favour and use Uri.encode() instead of URLEncoder.encode, as I wrote. -- Please describe what this means: _I am unable to receive messages using mail app_. You can't read your inbox?

Comment: Can you please describe the behaviour. Simply saying _not working_ is not getting us anywhere.

Comment: I used this Uri.encode, this time mail app is not working(means mail is not sent) in even any device(here i am using HTC one v, HTC wild fire s, nexus 7). Gmail app only working in both cases. But in First case(URLEncoder.encode), only HTC one V is not sent the mails using mail app but rest of them are working fine. then what should we do?

Comment: I presume you accidentially call `Uri.encode("Price etc", "UTF-8")`, which makes no sense. It must be `Uri.encode("Price etc")`. I was hoping you'd check the documentation first, but it looks like you didn't. It will be UTF-8 still.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23892/discussion-between-naresh-and-class-stacker)

Comment: @naresh I was offline. So did you succeed?

Comment: @naresh And you don't have problems with `+` signs?

Comment: ya it's coming but this time i ignore that. do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @naresh By using Uri.encode() instead of URLEncoder.encode, as I said.

Comment: I have no idea what _we are not getting messages_ means. It's not specific enough to think of any potential problem sources.

Comment: What i am saying is suppose we are trying to send messages using mail app but those messages are not received to recipients using  Uri.encode(). I think now it's clear

Comment: @naresh Sorry, no. Because you don't say where the failure occurs. Do you see the e-mail app start and does it show the composed message?

Comment: Stacker: yes it's start the email app and show the compose box  but when i am trying to send message then it shows the toast message "sending..." and close the email app but that message is not yet received to the recipient.

Comment: @naresh And you think that is a problem with the Intent?

Comment: Sorry i don't know that's what i posted.

Comment: Thanks. your solution is working fine. What happens is long back I created one folder for storing these mails. Accidentally that folder is overlapped with some other folder because of that i am unable see those mails. So i thought that those mail are not received. Now i saw that folder it's having lot mails previously test by me. sorry for this and thanks once again for activeness.