# Mail applications not in intent chooser

Tags: android, email, android-intent

On click of any email id with mailto: protocol, I want to redirect app to any mail application. For that I have used

```
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose Action"));
```

It works on several devices. But it fail to work on Nexus 7 and Medion Life Tab. They both have Jelly Bean installed. However, it works on some Nexus 7. In intent chooser it shows NFC and Quick send apps but not any Mail application or skype.

I have looked into following links :
[android - Mail app not support in nexus 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683071/android-mail-app-not-support-in-nexus-7) and 
[Android 4.2.2 - GMail app not in intent chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613033/android-4-2-2-gmail-app-not-in-intent-chooser).
But it doesn't help.

What can be the reason to such strange behaviour of some devices?

Comment: @prometheuspk Nope..Not any exact solution found.

Comment: Check my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255915/android-intent-chooser-to-only-show-e-mail-option/31547407#31547407

Comment: @PedroVarela If you put it in answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Why? To have a duplicated response? It is perfectly valid to link other previously answered questions.